# Memory Leak. FInding line number

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks

So this is a homework project first and foremost. My whole program is working, it was an intermediate/advancedintro project to deal with dynamic memory allocation. I can't figure out how to display the line numbers with the normal output. I've attempted to look at the other questions on stack about this topic but I cannot seem to figure out a reason that helps me. Any suggestions to how to make the line number appear?

Here is my `"LeakWatcher.cpp"`

```
#ifndef IMWATCHINGYOULEAK
#define IMWATCHINGYOULEAK
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
inline void* operator new(size_t nSize, const char * lpszFileName, int nLine)
{  return ::operator new(nSize, 1, lpszFileName, nLine); }
inline void __cdecl operator delete(void * _P, const char * lpszFileName, int nLine) 
{ ::operator delete(_P, _NORMAL_BLOCK, lpszFileName, nLine); } 
#define DEBUG_NEW new( __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define MALLOC_DBG(x) _malloc_dbg(x, 1, __FILE__, __LINE__);
#define malloc(x) MALLOC_DBG(x)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif // _DEBUG
#endif // #include guard
```

And my `main()`

```
int main()
{
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE ); 
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT ); 
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE ); 
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT ); 
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE ); 
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT ); 

   try
   {
      Directory().Run();
   }
   catch ( ... )
   {
      cout << "Uncaught Exception" << endl;
   }

   _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried printing `__FILE__` or `__LINE__` ??

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. What "normal output" are you talking about? There's no output code at all here, as far as I can tell (other than in the `catch` -- is that what you're talking about?). What's stopping you from outputting the line numbers when and where you want them?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : This appears to be MS VC++ code. _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks will dump information to the console if a leak is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that did occur to me based on your code is this. You say you placed all the debug macros into `LeakWatcher.cpp` and not `LeakWatcher.h` . I suspect this is your issue.

Create `LeakWatcher.h` with everything you currently have in your `LeakWatcher.cpp`. You don't need `LeakWatcher.cpp` so you should be able to remove it. Now use `#include "LeakWatcher.h"` at the top of **all of your `.cpp` files**. So it would look something like the following.

File **LeakWatcher.h**

```
#ifndef IMWATCHINGYOULEAK 
#define IMWATCHINGYOULEAK
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
inline void* operator new(size_t nSize, const char * lpszFileName, int nLine)
{  return ::operator new(nSize, 1, lpszFileName, nLine); }
inline void __cdecl operator delete(void * _P, const char * lpszFileName, int nLine) 
{ ::operator delete(_P, _NORMAL_BLOCK, lpszFileName, nLine); } 
#define DEBUG_NEW new( __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define MALLOC_DBG(x) _malloc_dbg(x, 1, __FILE__, __LINE__);
#define malloc(x) MALLOC_DBG(x)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif // _DEBUG
#endif // #include guard
```

Then in a file like **test.cpp** you can do this (similar to your test code):

```
#include "LeakWatcher.h"

int main()
{
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);

    new int[40]; // This should be a memory leak

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // This should dump with line numbers and file names

    return 0;
}
```

Of course this will only work if you are building `debug` versions of your project.

To get some other insights into overriding these heap routines, I found this [MSDN Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140858) valuable.

Comment: This is closest to what I'm looking for however my Visual Studios won't print out which line number that is occurring in. It leaves that line out.

Comment: I tried the above code on VS2010 and VS2013. Are you using an Express version by chance? When I took your code as you described and tried it `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` the leaked memory displayed without line numbers and filenames. After making my modifications and did it, the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` output the block information plus the filename and line number. Once you create the header file (`LeakWatcher.h`) you need to make sure you include it in **all** your cpp files. So if you have multiple cpp files you need to add an `#include "LeakWatcher.h"` to each.

Comment: I did that as well. It still leaves out the line number. This was after including the "LeakWatcher.h" in each .cpp file. And no I'm using Professional.

Comment: Did you try it with a simple application like I did above (I did new int[40]) with no other code? That would rule out the possibility that you actually don't have memory leaks OR the memory leaks are somewhere other than code you wrote. As well the header file should probably be the first thing included (before any other includes)

Comment: Professional 2010, 2012, or 2013? (I doubt it matters much, but I ask because it would be good to use as a tag in your question)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're asking about the actual algorithm of keeping track of memory that's been allocated but not released.

The typical approach of keeping track of where your memory allocation requests came from, for the purposes of producing diagnostic output is as follows:

1. Say you want to track the caller requested `n_bytes` worth of memory.
2. Allocate `n_bytes`+sizeof(const char *)+sizeof(int).
3. Store **FILE** and **LINE** in the first part of the allocated memory, and return the rest of the allocated memory as supposedly what's been allocated.

Something like this:

```
struct hdr {
   const char *file;
   int line;
};

void *my_allocation_request(const char *file, int line, size_t nbytes)
{
   struct hdr *p=(struct hdr *)malloc(nbytes+sizeof(hdr));

   p->file=file;
   p->line=line;

   // Here be dragons

   return (void *)(p+1);
}
```

(presumably, your `new` operator gets punted here).

Similar, when something wants to deallocate a memory block

```
void my_deallocation_request(char *p)
{
    struct hdr *h=reinterpret_cast<hdr *>(p+1);

    // Here be dragons

    free(h);
}
```

Before this can be a final solution, you'll also need to write a bit more code that goes into the "Here be dragons" part, and I think you could probably figure it out yourself:

A) Take each newly allocated memory and put it on a list of some kind (the first location of dragons).

B) Remove the allocated memory from a list of some kind (the second location of dragons).

Then, at the end of your program, you can go through anything that's left on the list. That's going to be your leaked memory, and you'll have the file and the line number where it was allocated from.

Note that you'll probably want to implement the linked list of unreleased memory blocks manually. Using some standard container will probably result in an infinite loop, due to container's very reasonable expectation of being able to allocate memory for its own use, which will loop back into your own new/delete intercepts, which will ask the container to allocate more memory, which will loop back into your own new/delete intercepts, etc...

There might be some implementation-specific issues here regarding alignment of allocated memory, but it's unlikely, and this hair-splitting can probably be ignored, for now.